# Programmatically Repair SQLite Database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, corruption

I have a need to try and repair a SQLite database from a .NET program if the database file gets corrupted. I have found several sites such as [Fix SQLite](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1468) and in the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q21) it describes that you can:

> Depending how badly your database is corrupted, you may be able to recover some of the data by using the CLI to dump the schema and contents to a file and then recreate.

Does anyone know of a way to repair a SQLite database programmatically in .NET?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are overlooking one important word: you can 'recover **some** data', this is not a repair!

If there is a sitatuation where a corrupted database could be repaired perfectly without user-interaction than it would not be corrupted in the first place and such an `repair` would have been a standard function of `SQLite`

Answer (score 2):

You might consider implementing your own strategy for database recovery.  You could store backups of the SQLite file and then check that it is OK using:

```
PRAGMA integrity_check;
```

If errors are found then you can revert to a backup.